# Inner Product Bilinear Form

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be the vector space $\mathbb R^2$.

Let $B$ be the bilinear form with matrix

$$B = \begin{pmatrix} 5  & 2 \\ 2 & 5\end{pmatrix}$$

Is $B$ an inner product?

Answer (score 4):

Yes $B$ is a matrix of an inner product since it's symmetric definite positive matrix: in fact it's simple to verify that this matrix is definite positive since its [leading principal minors are all positive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix#Characterizations).

Comment: what i dont understand is that an inner product <,> is symmetric if for all v,w in V, <v,w>=<w,v> for example, but what has this got to do with the matrix B? I cant see how <v,w> is calculated

Comment: If we denote $\langle,\rangle_B$ the inner product relative to the matrix $B$ then we have
$$\langle u,v\rangle_B=u^tBv$$